# inserting faulty message whilst list index is out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want `this was wrong try again!` to print when the input value is not on the board, yet somehow, instead of the printed message to show up when I choose a value outside of the board, the code breaks.

```
    def legalMove(self):
            if self.board[startX][startY] != False:


    def playerMove(self,tile): 
                if self.legalMove(tile, x, y) == False:
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            else:
                print('this was wrong try again!.')
        return [x, y]
```

the error

> if self.board[startX][startY] != ' ' or not self.isOnBoard(startX, startY):
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: In `and drag[1] in validMove` : ... is `move[1]` meant?

Comment: yes sorry @MrGoldbeere !

Answer (score 2):

You should **swap the statements** in the condition, such that you never get such an error:

```
def legalMove(self,tile,isOnBoard,startX, startY):
    # swap the statements
    if not self.isOnBoard(startX, startY) or self.board[startX][startY] != ' ':
        print('this was wrong try again!')
        return False
    return True
```

Although I would advice you to **do the printing in the `playerMove` method** such that you can reuse the `legalMove` method for instance if you would later build an AI player.

```
def isOnBoard(self, x, y):
    return 0 <= x < 8 and 0 <= y < 8


def legalMove(self, startX, startY): # remove arguments
    return self.isOnBoard(startX, startY) and self.board[startX][startY] != ' '


def playerMove(self,tile): 
    validMove = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7'.split()
    while True:
        move = input().lower()
        if len(move) == 2 and move[0] in validMove and move[1] in validMove:
            x = int(move[0])
            y = int(move[1])
            if not self.legalMove(x, y):
                print('this was wrong try again!')
                continue
            else:
                break
        else:
            print('this was wrong try again!.')
    return [x, y]
```

Furthermore Python allows chaining comparisons together, like `0 <= x < 8` which is more elegant.

Finally although I can be wrong, I think that valid move should only range from `0` to `7` (included). So `validMove = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7'.split()`.

Comment: Yeah I just simplified it a bit, actually the admin can change the board size from 4 to 10, thats why the `validMove`, I changed like you did, but now the valid moves also gets the message `this was wrong try again` ...

Comment: @Aurum: can you give an example of an move that is valid with this message?

Comment: I'll post a pic of and ex of the gameboard

Comment: @Aurum: I made some additional modifications. You call `legalMove` with two arguments whereas four are required, etc.

Comment: @Aurum: but `01` is wrong since there is no piece on `01`. That was one of your requirements (based on the function).

Comment: no you put 01 to place the tile there, which is on the board coordinates, if you for example input 90 (cause the coordinates only reaches out to 3) it should be a error message

Comment: and in this case i posted the onBoard coordinates are between 0 and 7 so if I input anything over (or under) that value of coordinate, it should be an error

Comment: @Aurum: please first specify what the difference is between `isOnBoard` and `legalMove`...

Comment: Oh sorry, `LegalMove` is a far longer `def` than showed, it basically checks that valid move is okay, that it is within the border, it's beside another tile etc. whilst `isOnBoard` is only giving us the coordinates of the board, and what I want now is when someone inputs coordinates "outside of the board" it should get an error message and tell let the player input another time

Comment: @Aurum: then you should replace the `legalMove` call with `isOnBoard` function when checking coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean?